# MySQL stored procedure fails on second call on same connection with "SELECT command denied to user 'user'@'localhost' for table 'view_name'

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-error-1142

I have a table called sales_observation_daily_summary which is a materialized view of sales_observation_daily_summary_view.  I have defined a stored procedure called sync_daily_summary_view_with_table that will refresh the materialized view.  Functionally, it works exactly as I expect.  However, I have a strange bug when calling the stored procedure twice on the same connection (a likely scenario when using a connection pool).  Originally this came up in my Java integration tests, but I am able to reproduce it on MySQL Workbench easily, so it shouldn't have anything to do with JDBC or Spring or anything in the middle like that.

```
call sync_daily_summary_view_with_table();
call sync_daily_summary_view_with_table();
```

On the first call, it does what it's supposed to do and returns normally.  On the second call, I get:

```
Error Code: 1142
SELECT command denied to user 'test'@'localhost' for table 'one_pg_someone_sales_observation_daily_summary_view'
```

one_pg_someone_sales_observation_daily_summary_view is referenced in sales_observation_daily_summary_view, which is referenced in the stored procedure.  The error message makes no sense as first of all, stored procedure did not object the first time it was run and second of all, that user has plenty of rights to select on that view.

I won't show all of the views involved as it is very complex, but the sales_observation_daily_summary_view is defined as a union of several other views thus:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
VIEW `sales_observation_daily_summary_view` AS
        /* Specific Stage and Observer */
        SELECT zone,
               session_date,
               session_year,
               session_month,
               session_week,
               phenomenon_group_id,
               phenomenon_group_name,
               stage_id,
               stage_name,
               observer_id,
               series_name,
               benchmark_id,
               session_count,
               session_value,
               benchmark_value
        FROM   one_pg_someone_sales_observation_daily_summary_view
        UNION ALL /* All Stages */
        SELECT zone,
               session_date,
               session_year,
               session_month,
               session_week,
               phenomenon_group_id,
               phenomenon_group_name,
               stage_id,
               stage_name,
               observer_id,
               series_name,
               benchmark_id,
               session_count,
               session_value,
               benchmark_value
        FROM   all_stages_someone_sales_observation_daily_summary_view
        UNION ALL /* All Activities */
        SELECT zone,
               session_date,
               session_year,
               session_month,
               session_week,
               phenomenon_group_id,
               phenomenon_group_name,
               stage_id,
               stage_name,
               observer_id,
               series_name,
               benchmark_id,
               session_count,
               session_value,
               benchmark_value
        FROM   all_activities_someone_sales_observation_daily_summary_view
        UNION ALL /* All Observers */
        SELECT zone,
               session_date,
               session_year,
               session_month,
               session_week,
               phenomenon_group_id,
               phenomenon_group_name,
               stage_id,
               stage_name,
               observer_id,
               series_name,
               benchmark_id,
               session_count,
               session_value,
               benchmark_value
        FROM   one_pg_everyone_sales_observation_daily_summary_view
        UNION ALL /* Everyone over All Stages */
        SELECT zone,
               session_date,
               session_year,
               session_month,
               session_week,
               phenomenon_group_id,
               phenomenon_group_name,
               stage_id,
               stage_name,
               observer_id,
               series_name,
               benchmark_id,
               session_count,
               session_value,
               benchmark_value
        FROM   all_stages_everyone_sales_observation_daily_summary_view
        UNION ALL /* Everyone over All Activities */
        SELECT zone,
               session_date,
               session_year,
               session_month,
               session_week,
               phenomenon_group_id,
               phenomenon_group_name,
               stage_id,
               stage_name,
               observer_id,
               series_name,
               benchmark_id,
               session_count,
               session_value,
               benchmark_value
        FROM   all_activities_everyone_sales_observation_daily_summary_view
        UNION ALL /* Benchmark */
        SELECT zone,
               session_date,
               session_year,
               session_month,
               session_week,
               phenomenon_group_id,
               phenomenon_group_name,
               stage_id,
               stage_name,
               observer_id,
               series_name,
               benchmark_id,
               session_count,
               session_value,
               benchmark_value
        FROM   benchmark_sales_observation_daily_summary_view
```

The stored procedure is defined thus:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sync_daily_summary_view_with_table`()
BEGIN

                /* Update any values that may have changed */
                UPDATE sales_observation_daily_summary tb, 
                       sales_observation_daily_summary_view vw 
                SET    tb.session_count = vw.session_count, 
                       tb.session_value = vw.session_count, 
                       tb.benchmark_value = vw.benchmark_value,
                       tb.series_name = vw.series_name 
                WHERE  vw.zone = tb.zone 
                       AND vw.session_date = tb.session_date 
                       AND Coalesce(vw.phenomenon_group_id, 0) = 
                           Coalesce(tb.phenomenon_group_id, 0) 
                       AND Coalesce(vw.stage_id, 0) = Coalesce(tb.stage_id, 0) 
                       AND Coalesce(vw.observer_id, 0) = Coalesce(tb.observer_id, 0) 
                       AND Coalesce(vw.benchmark_id, 0) = Coalesce(tb.benchmark_id, 0) 
                       AND ( Coalesce(tb.session_count, -1) <> Coalesce(vw.session_count, -1) 
                              OR Coalesce(tb.session_value, -1) <> 
                                 Coalesce(vw.session_value, -1) 
                              OR Coalesce(tb.benchmark_value, -1) <> 
                                 Coalesce(vw.benchmark_value, -1) 
                              OR tb.series_name <> vw.series_name ); 
END
```

I am using version 5.1.56-log on my local development box.
**UPDATE 1**
I have also reproduced the error on an Amazon RDS server version 5.1.57-log.

**UPDATE 2**
If I define the stored procedure to be `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` and execute it as root, it works fine.  This is not an acceptable workaround, but it might be some kind of clue.  (e.g. It is not a table locking issue.

**UPDATE 3**
The tables involved are InnoDB tables.  I'm not sure if it's a clue, but when I added a Start Transaction at the beginning and a Commit at the end, it took much longer to complete, but then got the same error on the second invocation.

**UPDATE 4**
I have simplified the stored procedure and still reproduced the problem.  It used to have an insert statement followed by an update statement.  It turns out that the update statement is sufficient to reproduce the error, so I removed the insert statement from the stored procedure above.

Comment: Can you reproduce it on another server?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my description to reflect that.  Both 5.1.56 on my local box and 5.1.57 on Amazon RDS have this issue.

Comment: Are you the only one using the views/stored procedure?  It sounds like  one of the tables in the view(s) could be locked.

Comment: Yes.  Especially on my development box I can guarantee that I'm the only one using the tables or views.  Is there something I need to do at the end of the stored procedure to explicitly release some locks?

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of autocommit?
    select @@autocommit;

If the value is 0 try to add a commit between the two calls as you could have an open transaction somehow
    call sync_daily_summary_view_with_table();
    commit;
    call sync_daily_summary_view_with_table();

Is the materialized table part of any of the views?

Comment: autocommit is '1'.  The table is not part of any views yet, although it was my plan to create some views with very simple filters on the `zone` column.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a transaction problem.  Try adding a COMMIT after the UPDATE and INSERT statements.  You might also want to try using InnoDB if you aren't already.

You should try the function like this to see if you get the same result:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`test`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sync_daily_summary_view_with_table`()
BEGIN

            /* Update any values that may have changed */
            UPDATE sales_observation_daily_summary tb, 
                   sales_observation_daily_summary_view vw 
            SET    tb.session_count = vw.session_count, 
                   tb.session_value = vw.session_count, 
                   tb.benchmark_value = vw.benchmark_value,
                   tb.series_name = vw.series_name 
            WHERE  vw.zone = tb.zone 
                   AND vw.session_date = tb.session_date 
                   AND Coalesce(vw.phenomenon_group_id, 0) = 
                       Coalesce(tb.phenomenon_group_id, 0) 
                   AND Coalesce(vw.stage_id, 0) = Coalesce(tb.stage_id, 0) 
                   AND Coalesce(vw.observer_id, 0) = Coalesce(tb.observer_id, 0) 
                   AND Coalesce(vw.benchmark_id, 0) = Coalesce(tb.benchmark_id, 0) 
                   AND ( Coalesce(tb.session_count, -1) <> Coalesce(vw.session_count, -1) 
                          OR Coalesce(tb.session_value, -1) <> 
                             Coalesce(vw.session_value, -1) 
                          OR Coalesce(tb.benchmark_value, -1) <> 
                             Coalesce(vw.benchmark_value, -1) 
                          OR tb.series_name <> vw.series_name ); 
            COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: These are InnoDB tables.  I'm not sure if it's a clue, but when I added a Start Transaction at the beginning and a Commit at the end, it seemed to hang.  It just ran and ran and ran and never returned.

Comment: Correction, it did not hang, it just took substantially longer to run.  I got the same error on the second execution, however.

Comment: If its taking that much longer to run, it makes me think that a large number of rows are being updated by the function.

Comment: Are you calling the function from a prompt, or from another function when testing?  I would drop the Start Transaction.  My guess is still that your somehow getting a nested transaction that's not Committing.  Call Commit once after the Insert and once after the Update.  Also can you try the function with just the Update part and then again with just the Insert?  I think that will help narrow down where things are going wrong.

Comment: I'm also wondering if the view isn't updated until the changes to the table are committed.  I don't know if this would cause trouble going from a Insert to an Update without committing the data.

Comment: I did drop the transaction stuff as it did nothing to avert the error.  Yes, there are a large number of rows being updated, which is why I wanted the materialized view in the first place.  The view has no dependencies on the table being updated, so I don't know why it would have to wait for the insert to finish without committing, but I could try that.  In any case, it works once (with or without the transaction).  It's the second execution on the same connection that results in the "SELECT denied to user" error.

Comment: Will it work twice in a row if you only do the update or insert?  Just trying to narrow down if the problem is occurring with one or the other.

Comment: Good question.  It turns out that the update statement is sufficient to reproduce the error, so the problem should have nothing to do with the insert statement or even having two statements.  I have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: This did not resolve my issue, but no one else did, either, and your answer was the most complete, so you get the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like it might be a problem with allowing multiple statements in one query

this(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-set-server-option.html) might be an option:

```
mysql_set_server_option(MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON)
```

or better during connection:

```
mysql_real_connect (
    mysql, 
    host_name, 
    user_name, 
    password,
    db_name, 
    port_num, 
    socket_name, 
    CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS)
```

you should also take a look here for a better explanation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html

Comment: This is not the issue. Through MySQL Workbench I regularly execute multiple statements separated by ';' and I can reproduce the problem in Workbench.  Furthermore, I don't need to do `call sync_daily_summary_view_with_table();
call sync_daily_summary_view_with_table();` in one go.  I can also reproduce the problem by executing `call sync_daily_summary_view_with_table()` once, waiting for it to complete, and then executing it again on the same connection.  It only works once per connection, not once per request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you guys have found a solution for this problem. I ran into same and was able to fix it!

The problem that I got just happen when I tried to make a select in a view through a procedure. Ar first time it just worked fine, but from second time foward it was reponding a command denied message for my user.

The solution was create the view with an "administrator" user, an make the same with the procedure (create it with an "administrator" user), with those processes I got it run!

The problem is that I don't know how exactly, MySQL uses another user to make the select through the view, it doesn't use your definer or logged session user, and at the second time, this "internal" user get comamnd denied from view.

I hope to help you guys solve this problem at all!